# Sentry with library sentry-java on WildFly10

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, wildfly, sentry

I try to connect via sentry-java library on WildFly but I don't know what add to standalone.xml. When I add file log4j.properties to my project it works but I don't have any log in my console.log

log4j.properies file:

```
# Enable the Console and Sentry appenders
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Console, Sentry

# Configure the Console appender
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p: %m%n

# Configure the Sentry appender, overriding the logging threshold to the WARN level
log4j.appender.Sentry=io.sentry.log4j.SentryAppender
log4j.appender.Sentry.threshold=WARN
```

Earlier I used library raven-java with constom-handler in standalone.xml:

```
<custom-handler name="SENTRY" module="net.kencochrane.raven" class="net.kencochrane.raven.log4j.SentryAppender">
    <level name="WARN"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <properties>
        <property name="dsn" value="https://host:port/1?options"/>
        <property name="ravenFactory" value="net.kencochrane.raven.DefaultRavenFactory"/>
    </properties>
</custom-handler>
```

Now I try to use sentry-java but module net.kencochrane.raven is not compatibile (it's for raven-java) and I don't know what module I could use.

When I put in my standalone.xml:

```
<custom-handler name="SENTRY" module="io.sentry.log4j" class="io.sentry.log4j.SentryAppender">
    <level name="WARN"/>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
</custom-handler>
```

I receive error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYLOG0019: Failed to load module 'io.sentry.log4j' for handler 'SENTRY'
```

In pom.xml I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
    <artifactId>sentry-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Anyone can help me connect Sentry via sentry-java with WildFly10? This article: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/migration/ is not enought for me.

Comment: It should be the same between `raven-java` and `sentry-java` except for the class names. I'm not sure I understand: what is different between your configuration that worked and the new one?

Comment: I expanded my question. I can't only change class name because my old custom-handler is for module net.kencochrane.raven. I don't know what custom-handler I can use.

Comment: Have you tried using module: `io.sentry.log4j` and class: `io.sentry.log4j.SentryAppender`? And you need to set the DSN differently now, which is described in the migration document or here: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#setting-the-dsn-data-source-name

Comment: Yes, I tried to use module io.sentry.log4j but i receive error: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYLOG0019: Failed to load module 'io.sentry.log4j' for handler 'SENTRY'. 
I set DSN in sentry.properties and it's ok.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's OK"? It works?

Comment: Can you show me which Sentry dependencies you added to your project? Or are you manually adding the JARs to the classpath?

Comment: DSN in sentry.properties is OK because my app send messages to Sentry - see first sentense of this question. I added Sentry dependencies to this question (see pom.xml).

Comment: Where is the `io.sentry.log4j` module located and what does the `module.xml` look like?

Comment: I don't know where io.sentry.log4j is located. I think I don't have this module.